# i want to save image in specific folder from UIImageView swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sqlite, uiimageview

i want to save image from imageview to specific folder Image is coming from Sqlserver. and i want to save link of it in sqlite for further processing i have written this code which is saving image in document directory but every time path is different. Please tell me what to do ?

```
 let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageee.image!)!
        let docDir = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .picturesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
        let imageURL = docDir.appendingPathComponent("tmp.png")
        try! imageData.write(to: imageURL)

        print(imageURL.path)
        let newImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL.path)!
       //aftersave.image = newImage
        aftersave.image = newImage
```

Comment: You are not saving to the documentDirectory, you are saving it to the picturesDirectory

Comment: i know but always printing different path whenever i rerun my simulator that is confusing.... really.

Comment: batter option is that just create one album of your application name and just save image into it.

Comment: how ? can you suggest me some code or any article?

Comment: @HammerClass check my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create one swift class file that i give you in link and just call that class with below line.

```
// orignal_image was UIImageView 
CustomPhotoAlbum.sharedInstance.save(image: orignal_image)
```

[Class File Click Here](https://gist.github.com/himanshu-benzatine/7f2c66d96216e38f06437a8a0f41687d)

**Most Important thing that you have to do add this line in info.plist file**

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>YOUR APP need access to your camera roll and photo library</string>
```

Comment: thanks @Himanshu it is really helpful.. need on last favour  someone down voted my question please up vote it i need to improve my reputation.... thanks again

Comment: @HammerClass ok i give you but Make sure next time you ask perfect question so nobody can put down vote and you can also give up vote to my answer , Happy coding.

Comment: well thats very helpful, but it could be more helpful, if you add an other function that can get all images from that specific directory .
Thank you

Comment: @HammerClass Can you update your library. Many error in it. If possible also add the one method/function for save video/mp4 file through this library.

Comment: what if i want to pass UIImage instead of UIImageView ? How can i do this ?